# How to retrieve selected mentions using ment.io and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ment.io

I am using [Jeff Collins Ment.io Angular js library](https://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/examples).

How can I get all the selected mentions from a text area

```
$scope.people = [
    { label: 'Joe'},
    { label: 'Mike'},
    { label: 'Diane'}
]
```

is my people object and I've selected Joe and Mike from the text area using '@'. Now I want to get those two

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "get" those two? Can you give an example of what you would want to get, for example, 'I want to have an array like ['Joe', 'Mike'].

Comment: Yes exactly, all the tagged users from the array

Answer (score 0):

according to:
https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io/issues/75

"ment.io is only designed to populate fields by inserting in data after a menu selection with an ability for you to create a transformation in your mentio-select function, and doesn't govern the data in the field. that's up to you to parse out as you see fit."